# AJAX Horizontal Scrolling with scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to create something like [this](http://designarchives.aiga.org/#/entries/+collections%3a%22AIGA%20365%3a%20Design%20Effectiveness%20%282011%29%22/_/grid/relevance/asc/0/27/90) site, I found many jQuery infinite scrolling scripts that allow you to load contents using AJAX while you're scrolling. What I need is very similar, except I want it to be horizontal and I want to set the size of the scroll bar according to the amount of contents I have. If you check out this [website](http://designarchives.aiga.org/#/entries/+collections%3a%22AIGA%20365%3a%20Design%20Effectiveness%20%282011%29%22/_/grid/relevance/asc/0/27/90) you'll see that you can jump from page one to page lets say 3 without loading the second page. Any idea how they do that ? their scroll bar is draggable too ! This is exactly what I need but don't know how. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jQuery lazyload](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) works with horizontal scrolling too.

Look at this example that I created [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Akz8j/).
 The site you are linking to is not a "horizontal scrolling" page. That's actually pagination not scrolling. If you want to do pagination then you don't need any plug in at all. Just call your AJAX when page or tab link clicked.